# Is it possible to inject HTML into a website to force-enable scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Okay, so this is a bit of an odd question. Facebook is trying to remove the feature that hides your profile from search, but requires you hit an accept button before they can remove it. I like my privacy, so instead I just used ABP to hide the dialog box and give me back access to the page. The problem is that scrolling has been disabled, so while I can interact with the content that's currently visible, I can't scroll down. Is there a way to inject HTML or JS that would force-enable scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

Seems as a job for greasemonkey

- https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

There are similar plugins for other browsers, Chrome have support for users scripts by default but there is a great addon there as well

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Internet Explorer can also offer this by adding Trixie

- http://trixie.softpedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it all the time and don't want to go to the effort of making a script you could just edit the html directly using either the developer tools built in to most browsers and inspecting the element.

Just right click what you want to change and select inspect element.

Adam